# Not able to click the Save button when dialog is not having the focus

Tags: download, autoit, dialog

I have written a script for file download for IE.
It works fine if the focus is on the download box. So explicitly I am trying to get the focus on the download window Sometimes it works , sometimes doesn't.
Earlier I tried doing by using the window names directly but it was not working so i have tried using windows but same results

One more scenario is : click on the download link in IE page, see the dialog box, open instance of chrome or opera browser. And run the script it fails. I am not sure why its happening.
Again if it runs on the remote destop and i am minimize or close the connection it fails randomly.

Can any one tell what went wrong? 
_Any help will be fine _

I am attaching the script example here:

```
AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode","2") ; 
; wait Until dialog box appears and timemout of 10 seconds.
$wait = WinWait("Download","",30)
$title = WinGetTitle("Download") 
$handle = WinGetHandle($title)
WinActivate($handle)
If $wait =0 Then
Exit
EndIf 
If (StringCompare($CmdLine[2],"Save",0) = 0) Then
$wait = WinWaitActive($handle,"",10)
If $wait =0 Then
Exit
EndIf
ControlClick($handle,"","Button2")
$wait = WinWait("Save","",5)
If $wait =0 Then
Exit
EndIf
$title = WinGetTitle("Save")
$handle = WinGetHandle($title)
if($CmdLine[0] = 2) Then
$wait = WinWaitActive($handle,"",5)
If $wait =0 Then
Exit 
EndIf
ControlClick($handle,"","Button2")
Else
;Set path and save file
$wait = WinWaitActive($handle,"",10)
If $wait =0 Then
Exit
EndIf
ControlSetText($handle,"","Edit1",$CmdLine[3])
ControlClick($handle,"","Button2")
Exit
EndIf
EndIf
```

Comment: I see one issue that sticks out to me, WinActivate() does not accept a window handle as an argument, it is expecting the title of a window.

Comment: Well I tried with Title also it didn't work so I tried using handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are working with a page in IE I would recommend using the udf IE.au3. This UDF comes default for integrating with IE.

The best resource you have are Autoit forums. The people there are very smart and know a lot about solving  . Link to someone who was working with downloads: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/90502-solved-handling-the-ie-download-file-dialog/